# testing de una clase abstracta que tiene un metodo constructor

Tags: php, phpunit

Tengo problemas a la hora de testear una clase de tipo Abstracta . Actualmente hago cosas como esta:

```
    $coche = new class extends CocheAbstract {
        public function hasRuedas(){}
        public function setColor(MyColor $color){}
        public function getErrors(){}
    };
```

Esto es debido a que mi clase CocheAbstract tiene los metodos hasRuedas, setColor y getErrors de tipo abstract. Este metodo para conseguir un "objeto" de clase abstracta me ha funcionado bien hasta ahora. Pero me he encontrado en la situacion de que otra clase abstracta tiene un constructor incluido:

```
abstract  class MetodosPagoAbstract 
{
    // aqui unos metodos abstractos
    public function __construct($param1, $param2)
    {
       // codigo del constructor
    } 
}
```

El metodo que he empleado hasta ahora no me permite enviar parametros al crear un objeto de esa clase para testearlo. He intentado con:

```
    $metodosPago = (new class extends metodosPagoAbstract {
         // aqui los metodos abstractos
    }($param1, $param2);
```

Pero el test se queja porque no se llama al constructor del objeto:

```
Time: 425 ms, Memory: 6.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) tests\Coches\Handler\MetodosPagoAbstractTest::testConstructor
ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function CochesBundle\Handler\Pagos\MetodosPagosAbstract::__construct(), 0 passed in /tests/CochesBundle/Handler/MetodosPagoAbstractTest.php on line 22 and exactly 2 expected
```

alguien se ha encontrado con una situacion similar? sabeis como se puede crear este objeto para poder testearlo?

Comment: Puedes crear una clase "stub" que herede de esta y testear el stub.

Comment: Lo único que veo raro es que falta cerrar el paréntesis abierto en `(new ...` para ambas clases anónimas. Quiero pensar que fue omisión al crear la pregunta. Adicionalmente, sería bueno que comentes si el constructor está definido como abstracto o no.

Comment: Hice un ajuste a la respuesta. Los argumentos no están pasando en la posición correcta para php7+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el código que muestras encuentro algún **error conceptual** que conduce a que no logres el resultado que esperas.

> **Las clases definidas como abstractas no se pueden instanciar** y cualquier clase que **contiene al menos un método abstracto debe ser definida como tal**. Los métodos definidos como abstractos simplemente declaran la firma del método, pero no pueden definir la implementación.

- La clase contiene métodos abstractos **debe ser declarada como tal** te hace falta **abstract**

```
<?php
abstract class MetodosPagoAbstract {
   // aqui unos metodos abstractos
```

- Estas tratando de instanciar y extender simultáneamente una clase que se presume  abstracta. Pero no lo es porque carece de la clave **abstract** (por eso chilla)

referencia [abstracción de clases](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.abstract.php)

**Ajuste necesario de sintaxis para la clase anónima (php7+)**
De acuerdo con la documentación oficial has debido usar la siguiente construcción ver[clases anónimas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.anonymous.php):

```
<?php
$metodosPago = (new class($param1, $param2) extends metodosPagoAbstract {
         // aqui los metodos abstractos
    });
// observa la posición de los parámetros luego de class
```

**Nota.** Tomando la sugerencia que hace en su respuesta @Osoria pordrías hacer luego de declarar la clase como abstracta: (la planteo para mostrarle como podría haber planteado su respuesta.)

```
<?php
class MetodosPago extends class MetodosPagoAbstract
{
   // implementación de los métodos abstractos
   // Métodos particulares
}
// uso
$metodopago = new MetodosPago();
```

Comment: Gracias @quevedo. Ha sido un error mío al transcribir el error en la pregunta (en el código es una abstract class). Lo he corregido en la pregunta. Como tal se está instanciando una clase que hereda de la abstract, e implementa los métodos abstractos(es un new class). El asunto es que no consigo que se le pueda enviar los parámetros al constructor de la clase abstracta. Estoy probando a declarar el constructor y llamar al parent. En un rato comento

Comment: @Jakala va a sonar tonta la pregunta ¿verificaste la versión de php? La sintaxis que usas para declarar la clase anónima no se parece a la adoptada para php7+. Si por casualidad estás testeando en una versión posterior debe fallar. **incluyo un ajuste en la respuesta**

Comment: como dicen por ahi, mis dieses :) No habia caido en la cuenta de `(new class($param1, $param2)`. Eso es lo que me ha servido perfecto. La parte del stub tambien es valida, pero en mi caso actual (debido a que estan casi todos los test asi) voy a optar por la inicial. Muchas gracias @quevedo y @osoria

Comment: Respecto a tu pregunta si, la version que uso de PHP7 permite esa sintaxis.

Comment: Gracias por la anotación. **Ignoraba que la sintaxis con los parámetros en esa posición también fuese válida**.