# Clase no encontrada al instanciar con una Variable en PHP

Tags: php, mvc

Estoy desarrollando una platilla MVC en PHP para practicar y utilizo `Index.php` como controlador central.

Para elegir el Controlador y el método que se van a utilizar recojo los nombres de estos por parámetros GET en la URL y después instancio el controlador en el propio `Index.php`

El problema es que si instancio el controlador de esta manera:

```
$class = new IndexController();
```

el programa funciona perfectamente, pero si lo instancio de esta otra:

```
$controllerName = "IndexController";
$class = new $controllerName();
```

me lanza el siguiente error:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'IndexController' not found

Os paso el código real para que lo veais:
(Index.php)

```js
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use Controllers\IndexController;
use Helpers\Request;

//$class = isset($_GET["class"]) ? new $_GET["class"] : new IndexController();

if (isset($_GET["class"])) {
    $class = new $_GET["class"](); // $class = "IndexController"; <-- NO FUNCIONA -->
}else{
    $class = new IndexController(); // <-- SI FUNCIONA -->
}

$function = isset($_GET["function"]) ? $_GET["function"] : "index";

if (count($_POST) > 0) {
    $request = new Request();

    $class->$function($request);
}elseif (count($_GET) > 0) {
    $request = new Request();

    $class->$function($request);
}else{
    $class->$function();
}
```

(IndexController.php):

```js
<?php

namespace Controllers;

use Core\Controller;
use Models\Users;
use Helpers\Request;

class IndexController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }


    public function index()
    {
        $user = new Users();

        $this->data["users"] = $user->getAll();
        
        $this->render("index");
    }


    public function prueba(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new Users();

        $this->data["users"] = $user->getById($request->get["id"]);

        $this->render("prueba");
    }
}
```

Si accedo a la URL:

> http://checkinout.test?class=IndexController&function=prueba&id=1

Obtengo el error mencionado.

PD: utilizo el autoloader PSR-4 de composer.

Comment: [Según el **ejemplo 3** del Manual de PHP debería funcionar](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php). ¿Intentaste con una variable en vez del GET? ¿Revisaste que el GET no tiene espacios en blanco o cosas por el estilo?

Comment: yo cuando hago cosas de ese estilo tengo que poner el new entre parentesis. Algo asi como `$clase = (new $temp())` siendo $temp='IndexController' deberia funcionarte... Aunque no es directamente tu caso, en mi pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/395799/testing-de-una-clase-abstracta-que-tiene-un-metodo-constructor  en el ultimo comentario me lo solucionan. Igual puede valerte.

Comment: @A.Cedano He intentado esa solución también sin éxito. Incluso si directamente hago; $var = "IndexController"; $class = new $var() también me da error. No encuentro solución alguna en internet.

Comment: @Jakala He intentado tu solución pero no ha funcionado tampoco. También he probado a quitar los paréntesis del new $class() por si acaso y tampoco

Comment: que version de php tienes? lo que te planteo esta probado con php 7.4 y funciona... quizas utilizas 8.* ? o algun inferior?

Comment: utilizo la versión 7.3. El problema me vino desde que usé espacios de nombres porque si creo un programa nuevo y hago esto sin espacios de nombre si que me funciona, pero claro, necesito usar espacios de nombres @Jakala

Comment: vale, Entonces puedes probar a concatenar en la variable el namespace? quiero decir, algo como esto: `$temp = 'Controllers\'.$__GET['class']; $clase = (new $class()); `.

Comment: si puedes, publica tambien el composer.json (con la parte de Autoload y autoload-dev es suficiente)

Comment: @jakala Agregando el namespace en la variable temporal si que me funciona, ayer lo probé y debí hacer algo mal. Sin embargo esto me acarrea un pequeño problema que no se si tiene solución. Esto me obliga a guardar todos los controladores en el mismo namespace, no pudiéndolos organizar por carpetas. Aunque no es un problema grave no se si se podría solucionar de alguna manera, ya que no entiendo el por qué hay que poner el namespace si ya utilizo el "Use Controller\IndexController". En teoría ya llamo al namespace.

Comment: creo que es mas un problema estructural. lo que sucede es que el index.php, que es la entrada, no usa namespace (porque se encarga de cargar el autoload), y no te va a encontrar de forma dinamica los controllers. Creo que la cuestion seria que hagas como otros frameworks, tu index.php sera el que cree una clase Kernel.php, que tendra su namespace, y ahi SI que puedes poner la logica de leer el __GET para dirigir a tu controller de forma dinamica.